# Не работает FTP

Tags: ftp

сервер Debian 8, стоит VESTA, после перезагрузки VDS закрылись все порты (21, 8083, 22), сайты и сервер работает как обычно. Командой iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT, меняя порт, открыл порты, заработал ssh, админ панель весты, ftp, но не теперь не могу скачивать и грузить файлы через ftp.. в чем может быть дело?

Cyberduck отвечает "Operation timed out (Connection timed out). The connection attempt was rejected. The server may be down, or your network may not be properly configured."

Comment: ftp открывает хост на порту *клиента* (не сервера, скорее всего 8083, Т.е. порт открывается "в другую сторону" чем 21.), и сервер должен приконектится к клиенту что б "скачать/зачачать"  файл, или содержимое каталога. Не помню как этот режим называется, можно а)попробовать перейти в другой режим б) смотреть по каким портам идёт блок.